# What to do with bugs on bell peppers

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, container-gardening, peppers, bell-peppers

I just noticed that I have these weird little bugs on my bell peppers. 
[image: bugs on peppers]

Doesn't seem to impact the growth as of yet, but I would like to get rid of them somehow. 
What are they called? How can I get rid of them? Are they contagious to other peppers and tomatoes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: aphids? let insects come by and eat them.

Comment: Problem is that the plant is on my balcony and I live on 12th floor... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did more research and ask couple of friends around. These are, in fact, [aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid). 
Here is a link to a wikiHow post on how to deal with them:
[3 ways to control aphids](https://www.wikihow.com/Control-Aphids)

Summary:

- Use household items: flour, soap water, hands
- Enlist Predators and traps: ladybugs, birds, other herbs
- Using Sprays: Oils, garlic, insecticidal soap

Given that my plants are on a balcony on the 12th floor, I will try to use water spray method, with manual "by hand" removal, and sticky tape trap at the stem.